# Get assigned roles in Azure Web App with PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Azure Web App using PHP. I enabled AAD Authentication, and got it all worked out where you have to login as a company user to access the site.

Then I created new App Roles using the `App Registration --> Manifest`. I have assigned myself that role, logged off, and back on, and within the `$_SERVER` variable I cannot find any reference to that role. I can find my username, tokens, principle_id, etc. but nothing referencing the AppRole I just created.

My question is, how do I get the App Roles that the logged in user is assigned? The only documentation I find on this is for .net or really old Azure classic stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens), the defined AppRole will be returned in id_token.

[image]

To get user's id_token, you can use Azure AD [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), and add openid to scope.  Here I use postman to acquire access_token and id_token:

[image]

And then I can get the id_token

[image]

By analyzing the id token, you can get the role of the user:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Using the variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_MS_TOKEN_AAD_ID_TOKEN']` already being passed to my web app, all I have to do is explode that token by the '.', then base64 decode the center one, and I see exactly what you see there without a single API call. That is exactly the push I needed in the right direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way i can think of utilizing Microsoft Graph API for this kind of operation.

Here is a sample Github Repo for reference:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-directoryextensions-web

For getting the user role , you can simply call below graph api :

```
GET /me/memberOf
or
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/memberOf
```

You can check below doc for further reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Overall this is how the flow would look like:

- Register an application with required set of permission
- Get authorized from Azure AD using above create application
- Use the token form step 2 and call the graph api to get user roles
- Proceed with the validation

Sample response look like below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
      "id": "id-value",
      "createdDateTime": null,
      "description": "All users at the company",
      "displayName": "All Users",
      "groupTypes": [],
      "mailEnabled": false,
      "securityEnabled": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That for sure looks right and thanks for your help! But I can't figure out how to grab the bearer token to make this API call :( That is one reason I was hoping to simply pull it from a server variable. Any token I try to use I get `Access token validation failure. Invalid audience`. But these API calls are newish to me.

Comment: Okay, I found this article about getting a token. I think I am on the right path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0 But that references a code parameter. Where do I get this from?   `The request body must contain the following parameter: 'code'.`